# How can I import a EU INSPIRE conform WFS in QGIS?

Tags: import, download, qgis, data-integration, wfs

I wanted to integrate this EU-INSPIRE-conform data in QGIS using this link for the WFS-import:

https://www.umweltkarten-niedersachsen.de/inspire/rest/services/SchutzgebieteNI/MapServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?

but it doesn't work. How can I download the data? Is that even the correct URL to integrate a WFS?

Thanks!